# I've been collecting tick level stock data. Is it valuable?

Tags: stocks

I have been collecting tick level stock data for about 200 stocks as well as the main indexes. Originally it was to test some algorithmic trading ideas I had, but I wasn't able to find anything that worked, so I gave up. But the data is still being collected on my VPS because I never stopped the collection scripts. As of now I have back to early 2017 (January I think).

Is the data valuable?

Comment: Considering that a quick google search reveals subscription services that sell historical tick level data, it seems that it's valuable to someone at least. Are you asking this because you're hoping to start your own business selling this data?

Comment: Where are you getting the data from? Will they allow you to re-sell it or use it for commercial purposes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It almost certainly has some value - there are companies that exist solely for the purpose of distributing that data.  However, you almost certainly got the data from one of those companies, whether directly or indirectly, and probably under terms that would prevent you from reselling it.  So your first step should be to look at the terms of use for the place that you've been downloading the data from.

If you're in the clear there, then the question is whether you can find somebody else who is interested in the same list of 200 symbols as you were, only cares about the last 2-3 years of data, and doesn't already have a source for that data themselves.  I'm not sure, but I suspect that anyone who knows that they have a use for that data already has paid for access to it, so you'd most likely be looking at hobbyists or researchers.

In other words, if you are wondering whether somebody might find it useful, then probably yes.  If you're wondering if there's a way for you to sell or license the data you've collected, then I doubt it.

Comment: It's _conceivable_ that the OP's _collection_ of data is _more_ protected than where it came from... according to [Database Legal Protection](https://www.bitlaw.com/copyright/database.html), a database of facts _can_ be copyrighted (under at least US law, as a "compilation"), but the underlying data cannot. Provided OP didn't _wholesale copy_ another database, they've probably done nothing wrong (cherry-picking values _from_ such a database would appear to be OK). The OP's collection of data should similarly be protected (as a compilation), but others could cherry-pick from it.

Comment: @TripeHound I was collecting it only for personal use initially, to test some ideas and for some coursework. I think that would be "fair use".

Answer (score 0):

The data itself holds **some** value, but that type of data is relatively easy to come by if you're in the market for it. You can either collect it on your own or pay a company who collects massive amounts of data on a broader range of equities (i.e. more than 200).

The raw data itself would likely be used for a higher level analysis, in which case, someone would probably want information on more than 200 stocks.

Basically, the question comes down to, *"why would someone buy the data from you vs. another company that specializes in data collection?"* (With all due respect)

If you had a way of running some type of analysis on the data, it may make it more valuable. You could then package it as a report with patterns and insights.

Comment: Because it's very expensive to buy from other companies... hence why I was collecting it in the first place. I'd sell it for *much* cheaper. Even the "affordable" rates from other companies approach $50/month, even for hobbyists who only want a small # of stocks.